# Checking case-sensitivity of a volume filesystem without writing to it?

Tags: c#, .net-core

As the title says: is there any cross-platform way of checking filesystem case-sensitivity for a volume without writing to it?

This is for a cross-platform application so I can't use windows specific APIs, and the filesystem might be read-only, so I can't do the "trick" of writing a file with a guid name in lowercase and check if it exists in upper case.

Is there any API for it that I may have skipped?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

- Get a list of files and/or subfolders in the folder you are concerned about
- Convert the first name to uppercase or lowercase, whatever works to make the casing different
- Check whether a file/folder with that name exists
- If it does exist, then the filesystem is case insensitive

Requirements:

- You can list files/folders and check the existence of a named file/folder
- There are files/folders to list ...

Comment: If it does exist, then either the file system is case insensitive, or the file system is case sensitive and both those files happen to exist in the same directory. Also, I don't know if this is a problem for the OP, but it won't work on an empty file system.

Comment: @hvd it could be a problem, but my main concern with listing files (which has passed my mind every now and then) is a) not having listing permissions, and b) slow filesystems with many files. If I was to do it this way, I'd do it a bit differently... list all files... check if there are duplicates with different casing on first instance, and then if there are not, go check for first file's existence with a different casing. This could work (again, unless the filesystem is empty), but my concerns with listing files are different.

Comment: Then again, I didn't mention performance on my question, so I'd not go as far as downvoting this answer... it does not serve my particular needs, but I don't think it should be downvoted :-)

Comment: @Jcl You wouldn't need a full list of files though, you could use `readdir()` and stop as soon as you hit any file name which contains at least one letter. That might work even better for slow file systems, though I'm not 100% certain. As for not having listing permissions, that's true but it's going to get tricky if you neither want to write nor want to assume you can read, that doesn't leave much else. (And I agree on voting; the downvote isn't mine :))